# How can I pass the numbers I pulled from the database to the javascript data section?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a Bar Chart. I used some libraries that I found on github to do this. But now I am having trouble passing over the variables that I pulled from the DB (just some numbers) into the data section on the javascript. If anyone could give some tips or help that would be great.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <script src="Chart.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>index</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Sales for last three months </h1>
        <?php
        require("files/connect.php");
         $queryJan = "SELECT sales_records FROM games WHERE sale_month='Jan'";
         $queryFeb = "SELECT sales_records FROM games WHERE sale_month='Feb'";
         $queryMar = "SELECT sales_records FROM games WHERE sale_month='Mar'";

         $Jan = mysqli_query($connection,$queryJan) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
         $Feb = mysqli_query($connection,$queryFeb) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
         $Mar = mysqli_query($connection,$queryMar) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

         //Information I want to pass to the javascript.
        $JanArray = mysqli_fetch_array($Jan);
        $FebArray = mysqli_fetch_array($Feb);
        $MarArray = mysqli_fetch_array($Mar);



        ?>

    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
            <script>
            var barChartData = {
                labels : ["January","February","March"],
                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data : []
                        //I want to put the information in here and it will create a bar chart 

                    },
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data : []
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data : []
                    }
                ]

            }

        var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);

        </script>



        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions!

Comment: Three separate queries for something that can EASILY be run as a single one? Ouch...

Comment: I know I don't have much time I just need to do it fast.

Answer (score 4):

Just get php to echo out the array as json...

```
data : <?php echo json_encode($JanArray); ?>
```

that'll do it.

EDIT:
You will need to get the data as such...

```
<?php
    ...
    $JanArray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Jan)) {
        $JanArray[] = $row[0]; // this fetches the data of the first column
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually you will need to reformat your array cause it will have the column name in it. See my edit...

Comment: Thanks a million Michael. Will give it a go when I get back to the house.

Comment: JSON is meant to be parsed before you use it. Something like this would be a bit better: `data: JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($JanArray, JSON_HEX_APOS) ?>')`

Comment: @maček Nonsense. JSON is a subset of the JavaScript language, you can safely `echo` it to JavaScript and the interpreter will use it accordingly.

Comment: The `json_encode` function will just echo it out as if you had typed (in javascript) `data : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: @MarcelKorpel, fair enough.